# Ошибка при выполнении кода (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, windows-10

Пишу код погодного тг бота и при его выполнении выдается ошибка:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000024D22D6C4D0>
```

Вот сам код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import python_weather

# bot init
bot = Bot(token="тут был токен")
lang = 'ru'
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL)


# echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    weather = await client.find(message.text)
    celsius = (weather.current.temperature - 32) / 1.8

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура: {celsius}\n"
    resp_msg += f"Состояние погоды:{weather.current.sky_text}"

    await message.answer(resp_msg)

    # run long-polling
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: У вас блок `if __name__ == "__main__":` действительно вложен в функцию echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы начали polling прямо в обработчик.
а чтобы обработчик работал надо сначала начать polling.
start_polling должен быть в конце коде и ВНЕ функциях.
вы сейчас должны просто убрать один таб в `if __name__..`

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import python_weather

# bot init
bot = Bot(token="тут был токен")
lang = 'ru'
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
client = python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL)


# echo
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    weather = await client.find(message.text)
    celsius = (weather.current.temperature - 32) / 1.8

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура: {celsius}\n"
    resp_msg += f"Состояние погоды:{weather.current.sky_text}"

    await message.answer(resp_msg)

    # run long-polling

# ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```